# How to change a property from Prism EventAggregator

Tags: c#, prism

Currently, the EventAggregator from Prism only accepts an action, i.e:

```
_eventAggregator.GetEvent<Message>().Subscribe(Method);

public void Method(string s) { Property = s; }
```

How do I get it to change a property, instead of calling a method to change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, it needs to invoke a method by design. You might be able to use a lambda to mimic the effect of setting a property (not in front of a machine right now, I can't try it), but it's still calling a method under the hood.

```
_eventAggregator.GetEvent<Message>().Subscribe(s => Property=s));
```

It's also good practice to unregister message handlers when you're finished with them using `event.Unsubscribe()` as per the [Documentation](https://prismlibrary.github.io/docs/event-aggregator.html)

Comment: `Subscribe` returns an `IDisposable` that can be used to unsubscribe.

Comment: @Haukinger I didn't know that, thanks! Every day is a school day...

Comment: Worth noting. Thank you also @Haukinger